# Problem with JavaScript for different Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am facing lot problems in my webview based application on Android. Different Android devices (HTC Legend and Samsung Galaxy Tab) react differently to my JavaScript code. As an example, If I pass a String from Java code to JavaScript and I treat it as an Array in JavaScript (using split method) then it is treated as character Array for HTC Legend and Android Emulator. But reacts differently for Galaxy Tab. 
Please note that I have updated HTC Legend to Android 2.2, the OS which we have on Galaxy tab. So both are having same Android OS.

I want to know if anybody else is also facing problems with different JavaScript support for different Android devices? 
Any information regarding this will be of great help to me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a library like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) to deal with the inconsistencies between platforms for you?

Comment: Thank you for the idea :)
I had thought of phonegap earlier but the UI wasn't that good.